# Si se da una condición aplica un formato de lo contrario aplica otro con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chicos, tengo un problema, si se da una condición deseo que se aplique un formato, de lo contrario que me vaya aplicando otro, sin embargo funciona mal, ya que me limpia cada vez que tecleo, este es el codigo que estoy usando, ya he probado con el keyup y el change

```
$("#Rnc").keypress(function() {
            if ($("#Rnc").length < 9) {
                $("#Rnc").mask("999-9999999-9");
            } else {
                $("#Rnc").mask("9-99-99999-9");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Que plugin utilizas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El único fallo que tienes en tu código es la comprobación de la longitud del valor del input.

Para coger el valor puedes usar [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) o [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$("#Rnc").on('blur', function() {
    
  if ($(this).val().length < 9) {
    
    $(this).mask("999-9999999-9");
    
  } else {
    
    $(this).mask("9-99-99999-9");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input id="Rnc" type="text">
```

Nota a parte: Te he puesto el evento `blur` por que te cuenta también el guion (`-`) como valor, también se produjo un error en consola (aunque no afectaba) y lo tercero pero más grave es que te cambiaba el último numero con el posterior.